# how to query mongo find / aggregate, based on objects that are not arrays

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I will look for data in rekap_rfid, and release all data based on year _2019, and can input custom year, month, and day

to be used as a monthly and annual recap I must take several values, such as year and date.

then data will appear based on the year and month that I input

---

```
 {
"_id" : ObjectId("5cc0273fae15393f68003c75"),
"email" : "admin@gmail.com",
"sandi" : "1a954924c5f82bd12d655b4c23cc8b84",
"peran" : "Murid",
"mengajar" : [],
"RFID" : {
    "serial_number" : "-",
    "status" : "",
    "rekap_rfid" : {
        "_2019" : {
            "April" : {
                "_23" : {
                    "Datang" : ISODate("2019-04-23T07:00:00.000Z"),
                    "Pulang" : ISODate("2019-04-23T12:00:00.000Z"),
                    "Status_kehadiran" : "hadir"
                },
                "_24" : {
                    "Datang" : "2019-04-24 05:28:07",
                    "Pulang" : "2019-04-24 05:28:23",
                    "Status_kehadiran" : "hadir"
                },
                "_25" : {
                    "Datang" : "2019-04-25 11:43:38",
                    "Pulang" : "2019-04-25T08:17:01.704Z",
                    "Status_kehadiran" : "hadir"
                }
            },
            "Mei" : {
                "_01" : {
                    "Datang" : ISODate("2019-05-01T07:00:00.000Z"),
                    "Pulang" : ISODate("2019-05-01T12:00:00.000Z"),
                    "Status_kehadiran" : "sakit"
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
"Kelas" : [ 
    {
        "nama_kelas" : "7A",
        "tahun_ajaran" : "2018"
    }, 
    {
        "nama_kelas" : "8A",
        "tahun_ajaran" : "2019"
    }
],
"sekolah" : "HighSchool Test",
"profil" : {
    "username" : "admin",
    "nama_lengkap" : "admin",
    "jenis_kelamin" : "L",
    "bio" : "-",
    "foto" : "-"
}
```

}

---

desired output results

```
[
  {
    "email":"admin@gmail.com",
    "_2019":{
    "April":[
      {
        "_23":{
        "Datang":ISODate("2019-05-01T07:00:00.000Z"),
        "Pulang":ISODate("2019-05-01T12:00:00.000Z"),
        "Status_kehadiran":"hadir"
      }
    }
  ]
}
},
{
  "email":"other_admin@gmail.com",
  "_2019":{
  "April": [{
    "_23":
      {
        "Datang": ISODate("2019-05-01T08:00:00.000Z"),
        "Pulang": ISODate("2019-05-01T13:50:00.000Z"),
        "Status_kehadiran": "hadir"
      }
    }]
  }
}]
```

---

so above the sample results I took all the data for **_2019** in **April** and the **23rd**

but if you find a better JSON structure to take the date and year in the results above I will use it

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also improve your question what is exactly expected with sample output.

Comment: thank you for the advice, I will edit it

Comment: Can you share your desired output ?

Comment: @UpvotePlease 
I have edited some of the above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still not clear with your schema and your desired result. For example, you have multiple Objects(key-value pair) at key "April" which is not the right format and secondly, you are expecting array at key "April".

Apart from that, you are saving year, date and month at the key which you should save on value. For example :

```
"Year": "2019" ,
"month": "April",
"date": "23"
```

Or you can refer to MongoDB [Data modeling](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/data-modeling/)

But still you can try query as below:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {

            "RFID":{
                "email": "$email",
                "rekap_rfid": "$RFID.rekap_rfid"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: { newRoot:  "$RFID"  }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            "data":{
                "email": "$email",
                "_2019": "$rekap_rfid._2019"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: { newRoot:  "$data"  }
    }

])
```

The resulted response will be as below:

```
{
    "email" : "admin@gmail.com",
    "_2019" : {
        "April" : {
            "_23" : {
                "Datang" : ISODate("2019-04-23T12:30:00.000+05:30"),
                "Pulang" : ISODate("2019-04-23T17:30:00.000+05:30"),
                "Status_kehadiran" : "hadir"
            },
            "_24" : {
                "Datang" : "2019-04-24 05:28:07",
                "Pulang" : "2019-04-24 05:28:23",
                "Status_kehadiran" : "hadir"
            },
            "_25" : {
                "Datang" : "2019-04-25 11:43:38",
                "Pulang" : "2019-04-25T08:17:01.704Z",
                "Status_kehadiran" : "hadir"
            }
        },
        "Mei" : {
            "_01" : {
                "Datang" : ISODate("2019-05-01T12:30:00.000+05:30"),
                "Pulang" : ISODate("2019-05-01T17:30:00.000+05:30"),
                "Status_kehadiran" : "sakit"
            }
        }
    }
}
```